# Error indexing Polish and Czech language version in Sitecore 9.1 Initial Release with Solr 7.2.1

Tags: solr

We seem to be getting errors similar to:

```
[Index=sitecore_master_index] Crawler : AddRecursive DoItemAdd failed
Remote error message: ERROR: unknown field 'description_t_cs'
Remote error message: ERROR: unknown field 'description_t_pl'
400
```

We tried troubleshooting and tried reaching out to Sitecore but since this is Solr related we did not get much help.

Searched and found some blog posts but none helped as we did set the dynamic fields and the field type analyzer properly.

We are seeing this issue only for Polish and Czech languages.

```
  <dynamicField name="*_t_pl" type="text_pl" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <fieldType name="text_pl" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_pl.txt" ignoreCase="true" />
        <filter class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.stempel.StempelPolishStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

```
  <dynamicField name="*_t_cs" type="text_cz" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <fieldType name="text_cz" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_cz.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.CzechStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

I was unable to add in the Managed schema to this post as the body of the post is limited to 30000 characters.

Comment: Forgot to mention that this works if we manually add the dynamic fields, but from a deployment aspect, it should work with the Manged Schema.

Comment: For `*_t_cs` in the dynamicField name, is that a typo? I think it should be `*_t_cz`, no?

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing `Stempel` filters which are needed for Czech and Polish. You need to copy `lucene-libs/lucene-analyzers-stempel-X.Y.jar` to `solr_home/lib` directory.

There are instructions on additional jars inside `solr/contrib/analysis-extras/README.txt`

Reference: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/language-analysis.html#LanguageAnalysis-Polish